# how to set this rule in CI pipeline in VSTS

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, code-coverage

New to VSTS

I am setting up `CI` pipeline in `VSTS` & while doing so, I am in need to set up Code Coverage validation if the Code Coverage is 80%+ then build else don't build.

[image]

I have enabled the Code Coverage option in definition,  but how do I set this quality check??

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT, yes I will post the ans soon

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and honestly **you shouldn't**. Arbitrary code coverage requirements are awful, because code coverage is a *metric*. It gives you information that may be useful when taken in as part of a big picture, but tells you nothing on its own.

Here is the only thing code coverage can definitively tell you: *"What code is not being tested at all?"*

Having 80% code coverage does not tell you *"I have 80% bug-free code"* or "*80% of my code is functionally correct*". It tells you "*Someone has written some test code that touches 80% of my code.*" Not that the tests are correct, or good, or contain assertions that make sense and validate correct behavior.

Putting an arbitrary code coverage percentage in place as a requirement has no value. If the team isn't already on board with good testing practices and writing good tests for new code, they will just game the number. You can write a test method that will run some code, make no assertions, and report a very high code coverage number.

If the team already is on board with good testing practices, they don't need a build to yell at them if coverage drops to 79%. Maybe they added something with a ton of tool-generated "designer" code that doesn't need thorough testing.

All that said, SonarQube (and I'm sure other tools) allow you to define quality gates (including required code coverage numbers) and fail builds if they don't meet that quality gate.

Comment: Completly agreed with you!! But I am doing it as part of learning

Comment: The next Quality Check that I am going to put it using some either SonarCube. Can you please suggest which tool is recommended for .Net applications as SonarCube

Comment: @Kgn-web I don't understand the question. SonarQube works for .NET applications and is fully integrated into VSTS build.

Comment: What about nDepend??